# How to handle callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN);

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, ojdbc

Have a stored procedure in Oracle 10g/11g like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE SP_SOME_PROC (  PRM_ID IN NUMBER , START_DATE IN DATE,  RESULT OUT BOOLEAN) 
is...
```

Using the following to code to call it and get the result:

```
String sql = "{call SP_SOME_PROC(?,?,?) }";

callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(sql);
callableStatement.setLong(1, theid);
callableStatement.setDate(2,  new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime()));
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN);

callableStatement.executeUpdate();

Boolean result = callableStatement.getBoolean(3);
```

the code above yields, however, an exception like the following

```
[10/8/13 2:28:24:736 EEST] 0000009a SystemErr     R java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 16
[10/8/13 2:28:24:737 EEST] 0000009a SystemErr     R     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getInternalType(OracleStatement.java:3950)
[10/8/13 2:28:24:737 EEST] 0000009a SystemErr     R     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameterInternal(OracleCallableStatement.java:135)
[10/8/13 2:28:24:737 EEST] 0000009a SystemErr     R     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:304)
[10/8/13 2:28:24:737 EEST] 0000009a SystemErr     R     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:393)
[10/8/13 2:28:24:737 EEST] 0000009a SystemErr     R     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:1569)
```

I experimented other combinations such as

```
String sql = "{? = call SP_SOME_PROC(?,?) }";
callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(sql);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.BOOLEAN);
```

but no luck!

Answer (score 1):

While Oracle has a boolean type you can use in stored procedures, it does not have a boolean column type that can be sent across the JDBC interface.  You are going to have to do some impedance matching (i.e. return int 0 & 1 or char 'T' and 'F').

This lack of a boolean column type is a holdover from ANSI, a source of much wailing and gnashing of teeth on the Oracle forums (look up 'boolean' on AskTom).

Comment: I'am not authorized to modify the SP, which is given to me as is by the DB guys. Any example to parse that thing in Java would be appreciated.

Comment: You may have to write a wrapper SP that converts the boolean to char or int.  Talk to your DBA and explain the issue to them, ask them for help.