# Java stored procedure calling in java program

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

What I should do is to create a Java stored procedure and later call it from Java program.

I am having problems executing the JAVA program - JDBCPiemers (below) with 1 parameter (I need to get out the String Nosaukums). Error: "Invalid column name".

Calling out the procedure in ORACLE works fine.

This is my stored procedure which I have loaded in database.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BeerBeer {

  public static void getBreweryInfo (int Raz_ID) 
    throws SQLException 
    { String sql = 
      "SELECT Nosaukums FROM Alus_razotaji WHERE ID = ?";//vaicajums
    try { Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:"); // Izveidojam savienojumu ar datubāzi
      PreparedStatement apstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      apstmt.setInt(1, Raz_ID); 
      ResultSet rset = apstmt.executeQuery();// SQL vaicājuma izpildīšana

      rset.close();
      apstmt.close(); //Savienojuma aizvēršana
      } 
    catch (SQLException e) {System.err.println(e.getMessage()); //Kļūdu izvadīsana
    }  
  }
}
```

I have created a following package with oracle.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BeerBeer AS
PROCEDURE getBreweryInfo(Raz_ID number);
END BeerBeer;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY BeerBeer AS
PROCEDURE getBreweryInfo(Raz_ID number) AS Language Java
NAME 'BeerBeer.getBreweryInfo(int)';
END BeerBeer;
```

This is my Java program in which I call out the procedure. However I cannot get it working. I am getting error: "Invalid column index"

```
package client;

import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCPiemers {
    // Norādam URL draiverim un datu bāzei
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL";
    // Izveidojam norādi uz datu bāzes lietotājvārdu un paroli
    static final String USER = "SYSTEM";
    static final String PASS = "asdasd";
    private String sql;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        CallableStatement stmt = null;
        try {
            //Reģistrējam JDBC draiveri
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("Izveidojam savienojumu ar datubazi ...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            // Vaicājuma izveide
            System.out.println("Komandas veidosana...");
            String SQL = "{CALL BeerBeer.getBreweryInfo (?)}";
            stmt = conn.prepareCall(SQL);
            int Raz_ID = 4;
            stmt.setInt(1, Raz_ID);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            System.out.println("Izpildam JAVA glabajamo proceduru ...");
            // Vaicājuma izpilde
            stmt.execute();
            //Izgustam Alus_razotaja nosaukumu ar getXXX metodi.
            String Razotajs = stmt.getString(2);
            System.out.println("Izvadam rezultatus ...");
            System.out.println("Identifikatoram NR. " +Raz_ID + " atbilst Alus_Razotajs ar nosaukumu  '" + Razotajs + "'" );            
            stmt.close();
            conn.close(); }
            catch(SQLException se) {
                //Kludu apstrade JDBC
                se.printStackTrace(); }
            catch(Exception e) {
                //Kludu apstrade klasei Class.forName
                e.printStackTrace(); }
            finally {
                // Bloks, lai aizvērtu resursus
                try {if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close(); }
            catch(SQLException se2) {} 
                try {if(conn!=null)
                conn.close(); }
                catch(SQLException se) {se.printStackTrace(); }
                //finally bloka beigas
            } // try 
            System.out.println("Darbu beidzam."); }}
```

Comment: Note.  It is not spelled 'java' or 'JAVa' but 'Java'.

Comment: @peter.petrov  The existence of the tag, with 4 followers, suggests otherwise.

Comment: What is the point of having a Java stored procedure, which just does a `select`, and calling that from an external Java program - when the external program could just perform the query directly over JDBC? Anyway, despite the 'stored procedure' name the Java method can be a function - you're already trying to `return` a value, which should be a clue. It should be a function with one argument, the `int`, which returns a `String`.

Comment: It is a school assignement, which requires to use JAVA stored procedure.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have updated the code using 1 parameter. However I am getting problems to get it working with my program now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return a value you need it to be a function, not a procedure:

```
  public static String getBreweryInfo (int Raz_ID) 
  throws SQLException 
  { 
    String sql = 
      "SELECT Nosaukums FROM Alus_razotaji WHERE ID = ?";//vaicajums
    try {
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");
      PreparedStatement apstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      apstmt.setInt(1, Raz_ID); 
      ResultSet rset = apstmt.executeQuery();// SQL vaicājuma izpildīšana

      if (rset.next()) {
          return rset.getString(1);
      } 
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage()); //Kļūdu izvadīsana
    } 
    finally {
      rset.close();
      apstmt.close(); //Savienojuma aizvēršana
    } 
  }
```

Then your package becomes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY BeerBeer AS
  FUNCTION getBreweryInfo(Raz_ID number) RETURN varchar2 AS Language Java
  NAME 'BeerBeer.getBreweryInfo(int) return java.lang.String';
END BeerBeer;
```

And you call it something like:

```
        String SQL = "{CALL ? = BeerBeer.getBreweryInfo (?)}";
        stmt = conn.prepareCall(SQL);
        int Raz_ID = 4;
        stmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        stmt.setInt(2, Raz_ID);
        System.out.println("Izpildam JAVA glabajamo proceduru ...");
        // Vaicājuma izpilde
        stmt.execute();
        //Izgustam Alus_razotaja nosaukumu ar getXXX metodi.
        String Razotajs = stmt.getString(1);
```

Note that the out parameter is now index 1 as it's the return from the function, so the value you pass in is now index 2. All untested of course...

Answer (score 0):

```
            CallableStatement stmt = null;
            String sql = "{call movecartrecord(?)}";
            try 
            {
                stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);
                stmt.setInt(1, order_id); //you can pass argument if procedure accepts
                stmt.execute();
                stmt.close();

                String name = stmt.getString(1);
                System.out.println("Name : " + name);
            } 
            catch (SQLException e)
            {               
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Here movecartrecord() is a stored procedure name and conn is a connection object.

Here order_id passes as argument.
If your stored procedure don't have any argument then just leave that line code.

Hope it will work and help you.

Here is a wonderful [code](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/) that show you how to perform it.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index. I am sure there is something with returning the String Razotajs as I have changed the procedure from 2 to 1 parameter. However, I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: 1 parameter - Raz_ID, I need to get out the String Razotajs using the JAVA program.

Comment: try by removing line `stmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);` because you are passing 2 parameter. look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236673/how-to-handle-callablestatement-registeroutparameter1-java-sql-types-boolean

Comment: Yes, but how do I output the String razotajs in my JAVA program then?

Comment: In my answer I have added a full example with link see that one you will get solution of problem from there.

Comment: Have got it ? I have also updated the code. Check it or see the link I have provided.