# Oracle not a valid function or procedure name

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I have compiled the following JAVA class and loaded it into the database.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

    public class BeerBeer {
      // Edit to return ResultSet
      public static String getBreweryInfo (int Raz_ID) 
      throws SQLException 
      { 
        String sql = 
          "SELECT Nosaukums FROM Alus_razotaji WHERE ID = ?";//vaicajums
        String toReturn = "";
        try {
          Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");
          PreparedStatement apstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          apstmt.setInt(1, Raz_ID); 
          ResultSet rset = apstmt.executeQuery();// SQL vaicājuma izpildīšana
          if (rset.next()) {
              toReturn = rset.getString(1);
              rset.close();
              apstmt.close();
              return toReturn;
          }else{
              return toReturn;
          } 
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
          System.err.println(e.getMessage()); //Kļūdu izvadīsana
          toReturn = "Exx";
          return toReturn;
        } 
      }
    }
```

I have made a PL/SQL package that is associated with a Java method call.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BeerBeer AS
FUNCTION getBreweryInfo(Raz_ID number) RETURN varchar2;
END BeerBeer;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY BeerBeer AS
  FUNCTION getBreweryInfo(Raz_ID number) RETURN varchar2 AS Language Java
  NAME 'BeerBeer.getBreweryInfo(int) return java.lang.String';
END BeerBeer;
```

When I try to call out the function by:
CALL BeerBeer.getBreweryInfo(3) I am getting error: not a valid function or procedure name.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your package specification compiled successfully?  It does not appear that the specification you posted is valid.  You would need to create the package and then the package body.  The implementation of the function should be in the package body not in the specification.

Comment: I tried making package first, then the package body. Still getting the same error message.

Comment: confirm that the user that is running the application has execution access to the stored procedure.

Comment: @DwB How can I check it? Anyway - this is the user that I have created a procedure with and the only one I use. Could there be any restrictions then?

Comment: The user that created the procedure can execute it (assuming you did not restrict access - something you can't do by accident).

Comment: Just a confirmation: you are using the same login when you create the connection from java that you use when you manually log into the database (maybe with toad or some such tool).

Comment: I dropped the procedure and its body and recreated them, still getting the same error message

Comment: @DwB I am trying to CALL it in SQL*Plus right after creating the package and its body.

Comment: silly question: were there compilation errors on the package body?  This will cause your issue.

Comment: @DwB there were no compilation errors. Made screenshot here http://oi39.tinypic.com/bg46cn.jpg

Comment: try EXECUTE instead of CALL

Comment: @DwB got error message: 'GetBreweryInfo' is not a procedure or is undefined.

Comment: What happens when you execute `select BeerBeer.getBreweryInfo(3) from dual`?

Comment: @rgettman ORA-00904 "BeerBeer"."GetBreweryInfo" invalid identifier

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the JAVA class definition or package specification? Both of them compiled without errors though.

Comment: Did you use loadjava to put the java class in the database?

Comment: I've entered your code on my database, and I can reference the function successfully, although it's throwing a java exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a function in your package, but you're trying to call it as a procedure. There is no procedure called `getBreweryInfo`, only a function. The return value has to go somewhere.

Assuming this is being called from Java, the call [in my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20564841/266304) still applies - you need a placeholder for the return value, registered as an out parameter.

If you're testing it from SQL*Plus you can do:

```
var razotaji varchar2(80);
exec :razotaji := beerbeer.getBreweryInfo(3);
print razotaji
```

Or in a PL/SQL block:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  razotaji varchar2(80);
  razotaji := beerbeer.getBreweryInfo(3);
  dbms_output(razotaji);
end;
/
```

What @rgettman suggested should also work:

```
select BeerBeer.getBreweryInfo(3) from dual;
```

The error message you said you got from that:

```
ORA-00904 "BeerBeer"."GetBreweryInfo" invalid identifier
```

suggests that you didn't do exactly as suggested, but wrapped the identifiers in double-quotes, otherwise the identifiers in the message would have been in uppercase. Oracle is only case-sensitive for quoted identifiers. As you (correctly) didn't quote the identifiers when creating the package, you should not quote them when calling it. So this is wrong for what you've defined:

```
select "BeerBeer"."GetBreweryInfo"(3) from dual;
```