# What is the meaning and use of registerOutParameter in callable statements

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc, callable-statement

I could have asked one of my colleagues this question but I figured that if I need to know this then so will other newbies so it is better to put it on stack overflow.

I am trying to work what the `registerOutParameter` function does. For example:

```
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
```

I get that registerOutParameter returns values that are returned instead of, or in addition to, a ResultSet. I cannot imagine how that would occur or what a possible use case would be.

So you know this is not laziness, so far I have looked at:

- the oracle documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html
- [How to handle callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236673/how-to-handle-callablestatement-registeroutparameter1-java-sql-types-boolean))
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286457%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/callablestatement.html
- and a heap of stackoverflow questions.

It just seems this question is too basic to be covered.

Backgound infomation, I am doing a tutorial on stored procedures at  www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/

Comment: _" I just cannot imagine how that would occur or what a possible use case would be."_ you'll need to better explain what it is you don't understand. Have you for example looked at database implementation that support `OUT` style parameters (or even `IN OUT`), like for example Microsoft SQL Server? IMO, the use case becomes clear once you know of its existence. For a very contrived example, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792(v=sql.80).aspx that shows 3(!) different ways SQL Server procedures can return values

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel, as explained, I am doing the tutorial at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/callablestatement.html. The tutorial contains the line `callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);`. I am trying to work out, does this just set the datatype for the queries parameters or is it doing something else?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, FYI no I have never heard of `IN OUT`. I checked the link you sent but there don't appear to be references to that - could you please explain that in your answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very tight to how stored procedures are executed in an RDBMS. Note that the execution of a stored procedure through a `CallableStatement` is very different from the execution of a `SELECT` query which returns a `ResultSet`. When executing such a query the RDBMS will return a description of the columns and the driver uses this description to know what to expect for the data.

Before executing a stored procedure, the JDBC specification says that you must call `registerOutParameter` for each OUT parameter. This is to indicate to the driver what data it should expect. Why? Because for many RDBMSs there is no way to describe a stored procedure. It's up to the user to define the out parameters through this API. The driver wouldn't be able to figure it out on its own. You can then execute the stored procedure and then call the getters on the `CallableStatement` to get the value of the OUT parameters that you have registered.